# DAX between (not directly) connected tables

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax, powerbi

I have a model of 3 tables:

[image]

I want to calculate the number of years a pilot has been active (i.e. at least 1 flight per year, regardless of how many flights):

[image]

I thought that dragging the PilotName along with the below DAX measure would solve my problem, but it doesn't:

```
Years Active:=COUNT(Season[SeasonId])
```

Is it possible to achieve this without any distinct count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be SUMMARIZE,i recreate your situation on my excel, creating some complications:

[image]

As you can see i indroduce Some Flightlanded = 0  and For same pilot and season id 2 different rows. I create your measure (Years active old) and my measure:

```
Years Active:=calculate(COUNTX(summarize(tableflight,tableflight[Seasonid],tableflight[PilotPK]),tableflight[Seasonid]),filter(tableflight,tableflight[Flightlanded]=1))
```

This formula not use distinct count and can answer to 2 problem:

1. Same row with different value
2. A row that we don't want to consider ( flight = 0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! After understanding your code I changed the COUNTX() for COUNTROWS() and I get the same result. Should COUNTROWS() provide better performance?